# A good way to modify dynamically changed data and submit using javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, web

I'm using django as my web framework. What I want to achieve is this:

**EDIT:**

Sample data in DB:

```
{
  "title": "hello there"
  "data": "{{ This is just some text }}{{ with some customized formatting }}"
}
```

Front end gets the object and converts it into something like (and displays it):

```
<div onClick="function_that_changes_content_to_hello_world();">
This is just some text
</div>
<div onClick="function_that_changes_content_to_hello_world();">
with some customized formatting
</div>
```

User clicks on the two divs, now the dom looks like:

```
<div onClick="function_that_changes_content_to_hello_world();">
hello world
</div>
<div onClick="function_that_changes_content_to_hello_world();">
hello world
</div>
```

Now when user submits the data back to the server, the server should get:

```
{
  "title": "hello there"
  "data": "{{ hello world }}{{ hello world }}"
}
```

Just looking for a neat way to do this if there is one? Currently I'm letting the server generate the divs and hand it off to javascript. Upon submission, the JS just dumps the whole dom to the server which parses through the divs, and it's not very elegant.

Comment: jqueryForms (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) has only worked well for me. If you don't want to use jQuery you can always look at how it implements things and make a custom version based on it (there might een be a jQuery free version of it somewhere already ready).

Comment: JQForms works well. you can set the target and replace it with server-response. If you show us an example code, we can help you.

Comment: Ok. for sure, Thanks! Let me post some of my code.